# Ansible Ignore_Unreachable is not working

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Hoppy holidays all,

I am trying to create a job that runs a yum command on all of my servers in an environment. That part is complete however I am looking to make the job continue running even if I run into UNREACHABLE errors.

Here is my task:

```
- name: "remove {{ service_to_uninstall_name }} packages"
  yum:
    name: "{{ service_to_uninstall_name }}"
    state: absent
  ignore_unreachable: true
  ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: You need Ansible >= 2.7.

Comment: :cringe: thanks @MattSchuchard, time to look into how safe it is to update from 2.3 to 2.7...

Comment: Is this the correct syntax for `ignore_unreachable`?  I am doing the exact same thing and it still fails each time I try to ping an unreachable host.

Comment: Looks like it's not working on per task level but at play(book) level. Not quite handy indeed. Ansible 2.9.2 here.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me.

My ansible version is `ansible 2.9.18` and below is my playbook worked for ignoring the unreachable servers.

```
---

- name: Install the package
  serial: 1
  hosts: dev
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false
  become_user: root


  tasks:

    - name: Install amazon efs package
      yum:
        name: ['packagename']
        state: latest
      ignore_unreachable: true
```

and Below is the sample o/p:

```
PLAY [Install the package] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install amazon efs package] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out", "skip_reason": "Host x.x.x.x is unreachable", "unreachable": true}

PLAY [Install the package] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install amazon efs package] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out", "skip_reason": "Host x.x.x.x is unreachable", "unreachable": true}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable the debugger and the playbook will run undisturbed:

```yaml
- name: Play
  hosts: all
  debugger: never
```

More on the debugger [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html)