# Ansible how to ignore unreachable hosts before ansible 2.7.x

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm using ansible to run a command against multiple servers at once.  I want to ignore any hosts that fail because of the '`"SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"1.2.3.4\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh"`' error because some of the hosts in the list will be offline.  How can I do this?  Is there a default option in ansible to ignore offline hosts without failing the playbook? Is there an option to do this in a single `ansible` cli argument outside of a playbook?

Update:  I am aware that the [`ignore_unreachable: true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961158/ansible-ignore-unreachable-is-not-working) works for ansible 2.7 or greater, but I am working in an ansible 2.6.1 environment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a good solution [here](https://linuxsimba.com/handling-unreachable-hosts).  You ping each host locally to see if you can connect and then run commands against the hosts that passed:

```
---
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: determine hosts that are up
          wait_for_connection:
            timeout: 5
          vars:
            ansible_connection: ssh
        - name: add devices with connectivity to the "running_hosts" group
          group_by:
            key: "running_hosts"
      rescue:
        - debug: msg="cannot connect to {{inventory_hostname}}"

- hosts: running_hosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - command: date
```

Comment: Just a heads up that the link in this A'er is broken, I looked for a replacement on archive.org but found none.

Answer (score 7):

With current version on Ansible (2.8) something like this is possible:

```
- name: identify reachable hosts
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  ignore_errors: true
  ignore_unreachable: true
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: this does nothing
          shell: exit 1
          register: result
      always:
        - add_host:
            name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
            group: reachable

- name: Converge
  hosts: reachable
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ inventory_hostname }} is reachable"
```

Comment: The question is specifically about Ansible versions before 2.7.